# How do I tell difference between object and string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javscript function (actually a jQuery plugin) which I will want to call as either

```
myFunction("some input");
```

or

```
myFunction({ "prop": "value 1", "prop2": "value2" });
```

How do I, in the function, tell the two apart?

In other words, what should go in the `if` conditions below?

```
if (/* the input is a string */)
{
    // Handle string case (first of above)
}
else if (/* the input is an object */)
{
    // Handle object case (second of above)
}
else
{
    // Handle invalid input format
}
```

I have jQuery at my disposal.

**Update:** As noted in an answer, if the input is `new String('some string')`, `typeof(input)` will return `'object'`. How do I test for `new String('')`, so I can handle that the same way as `''`?

Comment: If it is sufficient for you, you could use `jQuery.isPlainObject`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[jQuery.type](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/) may be interesting to you.

```
if($.type(input)==='string')
{
   //it's a string
}
```

Comment: This seems to take care of all the caveats mentioned in other answers, so far at least.

Comment: That was worth having JQuery in the mix, which, fortunately, it was already.

Answer (score 34):

```
if( typeof input === 'string' ) {
    // input is a string
}
else if( typeof input === 'object' ) {
    // input is an object
}
else {
    // input is something else
}
```

Note that `typeof` considers also arrays and null to be objects:

```
typeof null === 'object'
typeof [ 1, 2 ] === 'object'
```

If the distinction is important (you want only "actual" objects):

```
if( typeof input === 'string' ) {
    // input is a string
}
else if( input && typeof input === 'object' && !( input instanceof Array ) ) {
    // input is an object
}
else {
    // input is something else
}
```

Comment: +1 for the note about `input != null`, even though I'm not sure I have to care in this case. What does `undefined` return?

Comment: `typeof doesntExist == 'undefined'`, although you can just do `if( input == undefined )`

Comment: True - I was making weird circles in my head :P

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, the `typeof` operator will determine the type of the variable.

Beware though:

```
var str = 'A String' ;
var obj = new String(str) ;
console.log(typeof str) ;
console.log(typeof obj) ;

// Outputs:
// string
// object
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Is there a way to get to "string" from `new String(str)` as well?

Comment: +1, it's necessary to account for boxed strings. One way to fix this is to check for a method you know only belongs to strings — ex. `if ( some_var.substring !== undefined ) { ... }`

Comment: Or `x instanceof String` with the caveat of prototype inheritance

Comment: Then I like the `instanceof` approach better. Is there any way around the prototype inheritance caveat? Something like `inherits` or `implements`?

Comment: I believe that hasownproperty ignores inheritied properties.

Answer (score 3):

The `typeof` operator may get you what you need. i.e.:

```
typeof(myobj) == 'string'
```

(IIRC)

Answer (score 2):

You can;

```
function f(a) { print(typeof a) }

f({"prop": "value 1", "prop2": "value2" });

>>object

f("Some input");

>>string
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the command `typeof` returns the type of the variable.

I created a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge/d8dee/1/) It seems that the array returns also typeof as an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var a = {'a':'b'};
if(typeof(a) == 'object'){
    alert('object');
}
elseif(typeof(a) == 'string'){
    alert('string');
}
</script>
```

http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=5280

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `typeof` function:

```
if (typeof(myvar) === 'string') {
  // the code
}
```

see [here](http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/article.asp?ContentID=testing_for_object_types_in_ja) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [$.type](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/), as this is more accurate than `typeof`

```
$.fn.plugin = function( options ) {

    console.log( $.type( options ) );

    if( $.type( options ) == 'string' ) {
        // Handle string case (first of above)
    }
    else if( $.type( options ) == 'object' && options != null ) {
        // Handle object case (second of above)
    }
    else {
        // Handle invalid input format

    }

};

$("#d1").plugin( new String('test')); //string
$("#d1").plugin('test'); //string
$("#d1").plugin({'key' : 'value'}); //object
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/axDpp/)

**Edit**

Also if options is not set then `!options` would be sufficient